# Azure Kubernetes: OOMKilled - exit code: 137, Auto scaling did not kick-in to add additional node

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have the following configuration in Azure Kubernetes

[image]

while trying to deploy an application in the cluster, I getting the following error

[image]

If this is failing due to the resource(s), I would expect the cluster to add the additional node as per the auto scaling configuration which did not happen.

Any thoughts? what is the issue and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with autoscaling enabled in Azure, you may encounter OOM 137 because `OOMKilled code 137` means that a container or pod was terminated because they used more memory than the one allowed. OOM stands for `“Out Of Memory”`. OOM kill happens when Pod is out of memory, and it gets killed because ***you've provided resource limits to it***.
Another factor on which OOM depends on is [kubernetes QoS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/).

There are 3 different classes:

**BestEffort**: Pod with no resources defined, is the first to get killed when the node runs out of resources.

**Burstable**: When you set resource requests and limit to different values, which the limit - request is assured but if it needs to "burst" it will be shared with other objects and depends on how much resources at used at that point, not guaranteed.

**Guaranteed**: When you set the resource requests and limits to the same values, in that case the resources will be assured to the pod. In case nodes get short of resources will be the last to be killed.

You can identify your pod type using

```
kubectl get pod example-solrcloud-0 -o jsonpath='{.status.qosClass}'
```

[image]
To understand better why Kubernetes decided to terminate the pod with the OOMKilled error you can use

```yaml
kubectl describe pod <yourpodname>
```

You will see some message along with the error-

```yaml
Reason:         Evicted
Message:        Pod The node had condition:
```

You can also check your [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-scale?tabs=azure-cli) config, verify if you have set any resource limit on your container. If the memory usage is consistently high and autoscaling is not happening, it may be worth adjusting the node scaling settings.

```
az aks update --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <aks-cluster-name> --enable-cluster-autoscaler --min-count 5 --max-count 50
```

or from portal. Also try VM size to a higher config
[image]

Reference Doc-

[Automatically scale a cluster to meet application demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler?tabs=azure-portal)

[MS Doc memory troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/identify-memory-saturation-aks?tabs=browser)

[Fix OOM](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-oomkilled-exit-code-137/)

[Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518884/reasons-for-oomkilled-in-kubernetes)